# Pros and Cons of JAX-RS, Playframework scala (REST backend), Web Api

Tags: java, scala, rest, asp.net-web-api

First am not sure if this question fits here well. However couldn't think of a better place to get help. I've been tasked to list the Pros and Cons of each of these {JAX-RS, Playframework scala, MS Web Api}. I've done some research but couldn't conclude as I've not used all three to great extent. Have used playframework to create simple REST app. Have read the Web Api tutorials but have not implemented anything. Did research on JAX-RS but haven't implemented anything either. Also most of our developers are familiar with C# and introductory Java. I am more inclined towards playframework due to Scala,Akka,no server restart and scalability etc but not clear about the cons. One thing am sure is JAX-RS is standard Java EE and Web Api is standard MS stuff. Below are some of the app requirements:

- Purely REST backend.
- Proper authentication and authorization.
- Online secure payment {Paypal etc}
- Single front-end for both mobile and desktop
  {angular/backbone/knockout..}
- Allow users to subscribe as companies or part of companies.
- Be able to connect to different databases without App restart.
- Code maintenance and readability. Other members should be able to pickup without hassle.
- Scalability

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer because I worked only with playframwork 2.0 and JAX-RS.

Playframework is a MVC framework, you can use it to create some REST services but it's not focused on this kind of applications, so at least in version 2.0 it wasn't easy to add complex behavior like interceptors, etc. and you should manage authentication by yourself, I don't know if this has been improved in most recent versions of play framework.

JAX-RS is a specification to create REST services, there are several implementations like
Jersey, RESTeasy, Restlet between others. So JAX-RS implementations are built specifically to provide REST services in java. Most implementations have support to several authentications mechanism like OAuth, etc.

In my experience, JAX-RS is better to provide RESTful web services, and the code generated is in general more maintainable than the code generated in playframework, also playframework has a lot of things that maybe you don't need to use, but it will be loaded in memory when you start the server anyway. Akka it's a cool technology, but you can use it if you want it in any JAX-RS implementation.

If you want to build REST services using Scala, you could try Scalatra http://www.scalatra.org/

If you prefer java, take a look at http://dropwizard.io/, it's an embedded server that has Jersey (An implementation of JAX-RS) and a lot of cool things to provide RESTful web services, like metrics, etc, also it's easy to learn. If your team doesn't have an advanced java knowledge, this is a good option.

Playframework is great if you want an easy to learn MVC, specially for non java programmers but definitively it's not the right tool to build RESTful webservices based applications in my experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will wait and see if there are better answers. Did checked out dropwizard but it seems to still be using JAX-RS 1 and seems slow to evovle/catch up.